# How to handle callback function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The async function itself should make use of the lookup() function what I have used inside the  async function,but return the result inside the callback.

The parameters for the callback are err and res.
If an Error has been thrown by lookup() then it should be passed to
err, otherwise err is null or undefined.If a result has been returned by lookup() then it should be passed to res, otherwise res is null or undefined,I have other two tests for checking property as like user but I have shortened the code as much as possible. the problem is callback inside lookupAsync() function.

```
const users = [
  {
    "login": "norvig",
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Norvig",
    "likes": ["AI", "Search", "NASA", "Mars"]
  }
];

// lookupAsync()
const lookupAsync = (login, prop, callback) => {

// Only change code below this line


    const found = users.find(function(e) {
      return e.login === login;
    });

    if (!found) {
      throw "Could not find user.";
    } else {
      if (prop in found) {
        return found[prop];
    } else {
        throw "Could not find property";
      }
    }


//my current concept according to suggestion but trying to set in the     
code.

function mycallback(callback) {
var err,res;
callback(err,res);
}
mycallback( function() {
console.log();
});

};

test('lookupAsync() likes', assert => {
  const msg = `lookupAsync(<login>, 'likes', callback) should return         

  likes for the specified user.`;

  lookupAsync('norvig', 'likes', function(err, res){
    const actual = res;
    const expected = ["AI", "Search", "NASA", "Mars"];
    assert.deepEqual(actual, expected, msg);
    assert.end();     
  });

});
test('lookupAsync() with unknown user', assert => {
const msg = `lookupAsync() with unknown user should return an error
with the correct message.`;

const value = lookupAsync('nobody', 'likes', function(err, res){
const actual = err.message;
const expected = 'Could not find user.';
assert.equal(actual, expected, msg);
assert.end();  
});
});
```

Comment: then `throw "some error"`.. whats the problem?

Comment: my code is failing 2 tests, it has to pass 4 tests

Comment: which tests are failing?

Comment: Last problem was solved, please can anyone have a look at my current problem this is related to last one.

Comment: Can you edit your Post to only whats related to your problem, and provide some better/readable code part. No dev wants to read that mess.

Comment: If you can't solve your problem on your own, please respect the people, which you are asking for help

Comment: I am sorry if my previous comment did convey any types of inconvenience meaning, after trying all possible ways I got stuck here ''const lookupAsync = (login, prop, callback)'' where callback is not working, if possible anyone minds having a look at the code.

Comment: `Could not find user.` !== `Could not find user`

Comment: error is corrected, was that the only mistake in the whole code or am I understanding something wrong ?

Comment: can you do some `console.log` to dig into the problem?

Comment: What is this line doing `callback( function(err, res) {` ???

Comment: I have edited the old code by new syntax, trying to figure how to use.

Comment: what should the callback do?

Answer (score 1):

Let me do it for you

```
const lookupAsync = (login, prop, callback) => {
  const found = users.find(function(e) {
    return e.login === login;
  });

    if (!found) {
      callback(new Error("Could not find user."));
    } else {
      if (prop in found) {
        callback(null, found[prop]);
      } else {
        callback(new Error("Could not find property"));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, only second test is failing :( , I am so sorry to bother you again

Comment: check again, please also check the strings of the error

Comment: Everything is working fine, I must say you are an extremely talented programmer, my dream is to become someone like you guys helping in Stack Overflow, I want to thank you for 1000 times.